# How to find and replace special formats in word processors?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, find-and-replace, openoffice-writer, libreoffice-writer

Currently I have Word 2010 and Word 2013 Preview (and OpenOffice 3, LibreOffice + LyX 2) installed.

And I want to do this: I have long document full of content that is sadly broken down by paragraphs, 
while I need/want to have no paragraphs, but the content in one line each, separated by spaces or commas.

Now I found out that **Word** has "Special characters" that I can set as a variable in the "Find and Replace" options, but it just doesn't work! I also tried to put a wildcard ("^?") in front of the "^v", but it doesn't work either. **It doesn't find a single paragraph break.**
Please see this screenshot, this is the config I tried:
[image: MS Word Search and Replace]

The result should simply look like e.g. this: "**IMF (Hg.) 2003 – Annex A** Anzahl Seiten: 2"

[According to Microsoft it should just work](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/find-and-replace-text-or-other-items-HA001230392.aspx#_Toc282602052).

*If I could achieve this **in OpenOffice or LibreOffice** I would be fine with that too* of course!

But I checked both and couldn't even find such an option in their "Search and Replace" menu.

**What can I do to solve this problem?**

Please forgive me if I should've chosen the wrong terms, as you can see my MS Word is in German.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all **^p** with a simple space (i.e. " " without the quotes).

If any line breaks remain, also replace all **^l** (that's a lower-case **L**) with a single space.

Note: If your paragraphs have multiple blank lines in between, you might want to first replace **^p^p** with a single **^p** repeatedly till no more substitution is possible, then replace the single **^p** instances that remain with spaces as mentioned above.

Comment: Right, **^p** stands for an actual paragraph break, whereas **^v** stands for the printable character “¶” U+00B6 PILCROW SIGN, which is what Word shows at paragraph breaks in a special mode (“Show all”) and could be used as text character too (but isn’t here). The Search and Replace functionality of Word is rather confusing here.